# how to sum time and handle null value using case in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, sum, case

i want the result in single row, GROUP BY sys_service_id,stat.---------------

```
SELECT sys_service_id,
  CASE WHEN stat='Idle' THEN cast(dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0,cast(trip_leg as datetime))),0) as time) else '' end  AS 'Idle', 

  CASE WHEN stat='Long Halt' THEN cast(dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0,cast(trip_leg as datetime))),0) as time) else ''  end  AS 'Long Halt', 

  CASE WHEN stat='Short Halt' THEN cast(dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0,cast(trip_leg as datetime))),0) as time) else '' end AS 'Short Halt',

  CASE WHEN stat='Running' THEN cast(dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0,cast(trip_leg as datetime))),0) as time) else '' end AS 'Running'
  FROM testing1 GROUP BY sys_service_id,stat
```

---

but, this given result as follows:-

```
sys_service_id  Idle           Long Halt         Short Halt     Running
2823    00:33:12.0000000    00:00:00.0000000 00:00:00.0000000   00:00:00.0000000
2823    00:00:00.0000000    10:56:19.0000000 00:00:00.0000000   00:00:00.0000000
2823    00:00:00.0000000    00:00:00.0000000 00:00:00.0000000   01:03:13.0000000
2823    00:00:00.0000000    00:00:00.0000000 00:18:48.0000000   00:00:00.0000000
```

i want as :-

```
sys_service_id  Idle           Long Halt         Short Halt     Running
2823    00:33:12.0000000    10:56:19.0000000 00:18:48.0000000   01:03:13.0000000
```

Comment: Remove stat from the GROUP BY. And use SUM for the case expressions.

Answer (score 0):

A simple MAX clause can give you the desired results

```
SELECT 
  sys_service_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN stat='Idle' THEN cast(dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0,cast(trip_leg as datetime))),0) as time) else NULL end)  AS 'Idle', 

  MAX(CASE WHEN stat='Long Halt' THEN cast(dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0,cast(trip_leg as datetime))),0) as time) else NULL  end ) AS 'Long Halt', 

  MAX(CASE WHEN stat='Short Halt' THEN cast(dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0,cast(trip_leg as datetime))),0) as time) else NULL end) AS 'Short Halt',

  MAX(CASE WHEN stat='Running' THEN cast(dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0,cast(trip_leg as datetime))),0) as time) else NULL end) AS 'Running'

  FROM testing1 
GROUP BY sys_service_id,stat
```

Comment: Thank u so much for your diligent and quick response.Done now.

Comment: Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't include `Stat` in your group by clause, because you want a single record for multiple values of it.

Second, wrap your cases with a `MAX` function :

```
SELECT sys_service_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN stat='Idle' THEN cast(dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0,cast(trip_leg as datetime))),0) as time) else '' end)  AS 'Idle', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN stat='Long Halt' THEN cast(dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0,cast(trip_leg as datetime))),0) as time) else ''  end)  AS 'Long Halt', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN stat='Short Halt' THEN cast(dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0,cast(trip_leg as datetime))),0) as time) else '' end) AS 'Short Halt',
       MAX(CASE WHEN stat='Running' THEN cast(dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0,cast(trip_leg as datetime))),0) as time) else '' end) AS 'Running'
FROM testing1 
GROUP BY sys_service_id
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT t.sys_service_id,
       MAX(t.Idle),
       ...
FROM(
    SELECT sys_service_id,
           CASE WHEN stat='Idle' THEN cast(dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0,cast(trip_leg as datetime))),0) as time) else '' end)  AS 'Idle', 
           CASE WHEN stat='Long Halt' THEN cast(dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0,cast(trip_leg as datetime))),0) as time) else ''  end)  AS 'Long Halt', 
           CASE WHEN stat='Short Halt' THEN cast(dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0,cast(trip_leg as datetime))),0) as time) else '' end) AS 'Short Halt',
           CASE WHEN stat='Running' THEN cast(dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0,cast(trip_leg as datetime))),0) as time) else '' end) AS 'Running'
    FROM testing1 
    GROUP BY sys_service_id,stat) t
GROUP BY t.sys_service_id
```

Comment: Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.  (getting this error.)(trip_leg column  have datatype-time.)

Comment: @kalpna I didn't see this inner `SUM` .. check edit.

Comment: yes there was little mistake... i've corrected... thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You want conditional aggregation.  Move the `case` inside the `sum()` . . . and remove `stat` from the `group by`:

```
SELECT sys_service_id,
       cast(dateadd(millisecond,
                    sum(datediff(millisecond, 0,
                                 cast(case when stat = 'Idle' then trip_leg end as datetime)
                                )
                       ),
                       0) as time
           ) as Idle,

       cast(dateadd(millisecond,
                    sum(datediff(millisecond, 0,
                                 cast(case when stat = 'Long Halt' then trip_leg end as datetime)
                                )
                       ),
                    0) as time
           ) as [Long Halt],

       cast(dateadd(millisecond,
                    sum(datediff(millisecond, 0,
                                 cast(case when stat = 'Short Halt' then trip_leg end as datetime)
                                )
                       ),
                    0) as time
           ) as [Short Halt],

       cast(dateadd(millisecond,
                    sum(datediff(millisecond, 0,
                                 cast(case when stat = 'Running' then trip_leg end as datetime)
                                )
                       ),
                    0) as time
           ) as Running
FROM testing1
GROUP BY sys_service_id;
```